# high performance communication between a java app and javascript application on a single computer

Tags: javascript, java, ipc

We want to send huge amount of data (> 1GB) from a java program to a Electron.js program (in javascript) on a single computer.

What is the most performant (least response time) implementation for such a communication? (Some sort of Message queue or Shared memory or database)

Comment: What can of data you want to share? Can both program read and write on the same disk space? How about combining message queue and shared disk space? Like A write on a shared space and message B. Then B go and read from the shared space ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing memory with Java applications is tricky.  (It typically involves native code.)  I don't know about Javascript, but I expect it is that is just as difficult if not more so.

Message queues ... will depend on the message queue technology that you choose.  Typical message queues are designed for sending relatively small messages and doing it reliably.  (And they typically rely on a database for reliability.)

Databases ... reliable, but not designed for this.  For a start, they make sure that the data is safely on disk before it can be read by another transaction.  (This is the D in ACID).

My recommendation would be to use one of the following:

- File I/O using a RAM file system if you are sending the data in one go rather than as "messages".
- A UNIX domain sockets.
- A UNIX pipes or equivalent.

The problem with sockets and pipes is that there is only a limited amount of buffering in the OS.  This may lead to context switching.  If there is a mismatch between send and receive speeds, you are likely to get cause one end to stall.

---

Finally, moving 1GB of data will take a significant amount of time no matter how you do it.   Processing it is liable to take much longer ... unless the processing is trivial.   (And if it is trivial, you are better off not sending it).  So response times are not likely to be "fast", no matter how you move the data.